# Interstitial Ads hide immediately with unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm trying to add Interstitial Ads to my app. I have 6 consecutive view controllers. I have 3 buttons on VC #5. Two of which are unwind segues to VC #1 and VC#3. The third button leads to VC#6. I want each button to trigger add. I have no problem with adding Ad to the third button with forward segue. But I'm struggling with unwind segue buttons. The Ad is showing for merely second and unwind segue goes on.

```swift
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}

    func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
        let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        interstitial.load(GADRequest())
        return interstitial
    }
    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
```

I've tried to use unwind segue with identifier for one button and direct segue with button for the second one.

```swift
@IBAction func againButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if interstitial.isReady {
            interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        } else {
            print("Ad wasn't ready")
        }
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToInstruction", sender: self)

    }

 @IBAction func endButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

if interstitial.isReady {
            interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        } else {
            print("Ad wasn't ready")
        }
    }
```

I've tried to use performSegue in interstitialDidDismissScreen function. It kinda works, it triggers segue after add was dismissed, but it takes 10 seconds to go to the VC after As's cross was pressed which is not the best experience.
So, I don't know what else to try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not trigger performSegue immediately after showing the Add. Instead you need to defer it until the Add is dismissed. For this you need to move Segue code to interstitialDidDismissScreen callback. Like this,

```
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    if isAgainButtonPressed {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToInstruction", sender: self)
        return
    }
    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}
```

And you set isAgainButtonPressed to true inside againButtonPresed method.

Comment: That's an option, but I just don't understand: if in case with "forward segue" it shows ad until user closes it -> segue triggers after ad was dismissed and I don't need to use DispatchQueue. But unwind segue triggers immediately. There must be an option to make unwind segue behave as forward one.

Comment: In case of unwind segue the viewController that is dismissed is deallocated. That is not the case with forward segue. The viewController that pushes other viewController will still be around.

Comment: @VadimKat I updated the answer with much better logic. Take a look.